# Сформировать массив структур данных о книгах в форме: автор, название книги, издательство, год издание.

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка, структуры

Сформировать массив структур данных о книгах в форме: автор, название книги, издательство, год издание. Вывести данные о книгах в порядке убывания лет изданий.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#define N 4
#define M 30
using namespace std;
struct books
{
char *author;
char *name;
char *edition;
int year;
};



int main()
{
books d[N] = {};
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    cout << i + 1 << "Book" << endl;
    cout << "Input author" << endl;
    d[i].author = new char[M];
    cin.getline(d[i].author, M);

    cout << "Input name" << endl;
    d[i].name = new char[M];
    cin.getline(d[i].name, M);

    cout << "Input edition" << endl;
    d[i].edition = new char[M];
    cin.getline(d[i].edition, M);

    cout << "Input the year of publication" << endl;
    cin >> d[i].year;
    cin.get();

    cout << endl;
    system("cls");
}


int Max, Min;
Max = d[0].year;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (d[i].year > Max)
    {
        Max = d[i].year;
    }
}
cout << Max<<endl;
Min = d[0].year;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (d[i].year<Min)
    {
        Min = d[i].year;
    }
}
cout << Min<<endl;
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Не знаю как вывести данные в порядке убывания лет издательства. Возможно у кого-то есть идеи. Помогите.

Comment: Надо просто отсортировать массив структур, используя либо стандартный алгоритм std::sort, либо самому написать какую-нибудь простую сортировку, как, например, пузырьковую сортировку.

Comment: оно отсортирует только даты, а я потеряю индексы элементов

Comment: Я не понял, что вы имеете в виду. Будет отсортирован массив структур в соответствии со значениями поля year.

Comment: @toshka-pitoshka, индексы - имеется в виду, что нужно сохранять порядок добавления элементов? Заведите поле `.order` и пишите в него значение `i` на каждом цикле добавления. Но мне кажется что вы о чём-то другом...

Comment: @toshka-pitoshka Непоняно также, почему вы в структуре объявили указатели вместо символьных массивов, когда последние имеют небольшой размер? Если вы будете иметь дело с указателями, то затем вам надо будет удалить все выделенную память.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++){
    for (int j = N; j > i; j--){
        if (d[j].year>d[j - 1].year){
            books temp = d[j - 1];
            d[j - 1] = d[j];
            d[j] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Вот набросал. Возможно вы это имели ввиду. Мы создаем временную переменную temp типа books внутри сортировки пузырьком по убыванию, с помощью которой мы производим то что делает функция swap(есть такая в C++) только структурами.